# Javascript process function after double callback

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a problem with JavaScript callback functions. I'm using node Js and node-mysql to process mysql queries. When new users registered i need to do 2 db checks if This email already registered and if this nickname already exists and after this create INSERT statement. But the problem is that i don't know how to catch when email checked and nickname checked because they have 2 different callback functions. Please help me how to do this best way.

1. Console.log looked like this!
2. Checking nickname
3. Checking Email!
4. Inserting new row! -- THIS Must be last but it's here :(((
5. Nickname
   CallBack!
6. Email CallBack!

   ```
   checkNickName(nickname);  
   var checkMail = checkEmail(email);

   if(!checkMail){  // The problem is when this runs CallBack still not received from Mail and from NickName too
   console.log('Inserting new row!');
   connection.query("INSERT INTO `user` (`email`, `password`, `nickname`, `auth`, `token`, `balance`, `role`, `language`, `last_visit`, `register_date`) VALUES ('"+email+"', '"+password+"', '"+nickname+"', '"+auth+"', '"+token+"', '"+balance+"', '"+role+"', '"+language+"', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '"+registerDate+"');", function(err, rows, fields) {
       if (err) return 2;

       console.log(rows);

       return 3;
   });
   }




   function checkNickName(nickname){
       console.log('Checking nickname');
       connection.query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE `nickname` = '"+nickname+"'", function(err, rows, fields) {
           if (err) callback(err);

           callback(rows);
       });

       function callback(res){
           console.log('Nickname CallBack!');
           if (!res) { nickname = nickname + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1); }
           return res;
       }
   }

   function checkEmail(email){
       console.log('Checking Email!');
       connection.query("SELECT id FROM user WHERE `email` = '"+email+"'", function(err, rows, fields) {
           if (err) callback('email',false);


           callback(rows);
       });

       function callback(res){
           console.log('Email CallBack!');
           if (!res) { nickname = nickname + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1); }
           return res;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

At the start of the function let us say you have a var counter = 0;

In check mail -> counter++;

In check nick name -> counter++;

now call a function in parallel to check mail, check nick name, let us name it as checkStatus

```
function checkStatus(){
    if(counter == 2) {
            // Call the callback
    } else {
        setTimeout(checkStatus, 1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes i thinked about timers, but i hope that there are some another solution without timers...

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of achieving it without timers.

```
callfunction("event1"); // call this function on execution of event 1
callfunction("event2"); // call this function one execution of event 2
var eventObj = {
        event1: false,
        event2: false
}; // event object

// function
function callfunction(eventFrom) {


if(eventFrom === "event1") {

     eventObj.event1 = true;
 } else {
    eventObj.event2 = true;
 }
// if condition will be true only when both the events are fired
 if(eventObj.event2 === true && eventObj.event1 === true) {

     // callback function
 } 

}
```